# Found NextJs Adding Extra Code after </html> tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When inspecting the page source of my website, I noticed that a significant amount of code is appended after the closing  tag. This additional code includes the entire content of the page, resulting in duplication.

How can I fix it?

```
</body></html><script>(self.__next_f=self.__next_f||[]).push([0])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"1:HL[\"/_next/static/media/2aaf0723e720e8b9-s.p.woff2\",{\"as\":\"font\",\"type\":\"font/woff2\"}]\n2:HL[\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1685346700397\",{\"as\":\"style\"}]\n0:\"$L3\"\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"4:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js\",\"chunks\":[\"webpack:static/chunks/webpack.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n6:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js\",\"chunks\":[\"webpack:static/chunks/webpack.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n7:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/script.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app/layout:static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n8:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./src/components/Header.js\",\"chunks\":["])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"\"app/layout:static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n9:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app/(site)/about/page:static/chunks/app/(site)/about/page.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\na:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app/(site)/about/page:static/chunks/app/(site)/about/page.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\nb:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:st"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"atic/chunks/app-client-internals.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\nc:I{\"id\":\"(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:static/chunks/app-client-internals.js\"],\"name\":\"\",\"async\":false}\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"3:[[[\"$\",\"link\",\"0\",
```

Comment: I think this intentional just diffing between the static and the client side to have it always ready. I don't think you necessarily fix anything per se, that's just the nature of next. But I'm rather posting this in a comment because I'm not sure about this, just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems there is an issue reported here and a fix, but I did not understand what the fix was. I will highly appreciate any hints I get from anyone.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/50056